# Strange Sound produced by ffmpeg and SDL

Tags: c, ffmpeg, sdl, libavcodec

I'm following the updated version of the original dranger.com/ffmpeg tutorial at https://github.com/mpenkov/ffmpeg-tutorial

The third step(Source code: https://github.com/mpenkov/ffmpeg-tutorial/blob/master/tutorial03.c) adds sound, but the sound produced is strange.
When the audio stream is AAC I only hear static.
When the audio stream is MP3 I hear a very high pitched version of the sound.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had the same exact issue. After days of trying, I figured out it was something wrong with the latest build that I was using from Zeranoe.

If you are using Zeranoe builds as well, try using the 26c531c build (anything above it will produce the issue).

Comment: I know it's late but thanks, I'll try this out. I was using the Zeranoe build.

Comment: do zeranoe builds still fail here?

Comment: I compiled ffmpeg manually. It sill gives me strange sound for aac audio. It is fine with mp2 audio. Any guidance? Thank you.