# FFmpeg 1.0 < causing audio playback issues

Tags: c++, c, android-ndk, ffmpeg

I have an audio streamer based on ffplay. It works great using ffmpeg 0.11 but when I use ffmpeg 1.0 or the latest 1.2 release the audio seems to be decoded or played weirdly.

Essentially it sounds like chipmunks with mp3 streams and with aac streams I hear tons of static barely hearing the actual stream and the actual stream sounds slow.

Any ideas the possible changes in ffmpeg that could have caused these types of issues?

Similar issue was posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452817/strange-sound-produced-by-ffmpeg-and-sdl?rq=1) but no actual answer about what is going on. Supposedly [this code](https://github.com/chelyaev/ffmpeg-tutorial/blob/master/tutorial03.c) reproduces the same issue.

**UPDATE 1:**
I have done a step by step copy from ffplay and still no luck! :/ The channel and sampling rate look correct so there must be something internally that is returning a weird decoded format?

Comment: It could be some api changes, no? I am guessing you used the libraries. 0.11 and 1.0 or 1.2 are not guaranteed to be api compatible with each other and in all probability they aren't. Perhaps you should check out the ffplay source again for details on usage of internal functions that you used.

Comment: Yeah, I took a look at ffplay and didn't see too many changes. I did a diff between 0.11 and 1.0 releases of ffplay. There where some changes but I didn't spot any difference on opening and using a decoder. I'll have to take one more look...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pCodecCtx->request_sample_fmt = AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16
doesn't change the behavior! I didn't find any better solution than using swr_convert to convert audio sample from AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLT to AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16.

Comment: I'm giving you the answer since it is exactly what I ended up doing. At the beginning I was lucky my answer worked but then I realized that with other formats the issue persisted. The answer was to convert the decoder returned PCM data to the one Android PCM player accepts.

Answer (score 1):

Found a fix... So initially it sounded like something wasn't matching correctly with the decoded raw PCM data and my PCM player. I took a deeper look at what was being returned by the decoder and any potential differences. Turns out that the default decoded format has changed from AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16 to AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16P. The fix was to simply specify `pCodecCtx->request_sample_fmt = AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16;` before opening the decoder.

Any feedback if this is a bad idea? I'm concerned if there might be issues with other formats and potential performance issues...